# How to randomly sample 10 rows, where the 2nd row has to be at a certain distance from the 1st?

Tags: r, random, constraints, sample

I have generated a dataframe which contains 100 rows and 3 columns: one with an x-coordinate, one with a y-coordinate, and one with "level" which is a variable I use as a constraint. I want to randomly sample 10 coordinates from these 100 at Level 1. For this, I have used the sample function in R, randomly selecting 10 rows.

However, some of the coordinates end up being too close to each other, so I want to add a second constraint that says the sample function has to skip at least 5 rows from any selected random row. How do I do this?

This is what I have now:

```
newdf <- df[sample(which(df$level == 1 ) , 10 ) , ]
```

Comment: A naive approach would reject sampling, you sample the value then if it's too close you sample it again

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not too big then you could do it step by step and eliminate from the available sampling pool each time.

```
foo <- function(available, n) {
  selected <- list()
  while (length(selected) < n) {
    row <- sample(available, size = 1L)
    selected[[length(selected) + 1L]] <- row
    available <- setdiff(available, seq(row - 5L, row + 5L))
  }
  unlist(selected)
}

df[foo(which(df$level == 1L), 10L), ]

#      x   y level
# 12 142 189     1
# 51 310  89     1
# 77 730 227     1
# 41 520 235     1
# 19 739 366     1
# 28 686 221     1
# 60 433 471     1
# 3  298 840     1
# 99 570 387     1
# 93 266 723     1
```

Reproducible data

```
set.seed(422)
df <- data.frame(
  x     = sample(1:1000, size = 100), 
  y     = sample(1:1000, size = 100),
  level = sample(1:4,    size = 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```